# Null Pointer exception on Indexed Container Vaadin

Tags: java, hibernate, vaadin

I am using the FilterTable addon of vaadin. 
I am getting a NullPointerException on the following code, but unable to find the reason of this.

```
  cont = new IndexedContainer()
  cont.addContainerProperty("Patient", String.class, null);
  cont.addContainerProperty("Date Of Service", String.class,null);
  cont.addContainerProperty("Provider", String.class, null);

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Iterator<?> iterator = session.createQuery("FROM ConvertVisitToBillingV WHERE ready_for_billing = '0'").list().iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){

                ConvertVisitToBillingV var = (ConvertVisitToBillingV) iterator.next();

                Visits v = (Visits) session.load(Visits.class, var.getVisitId());
                Appointments app = (Appointments)session.load(Appointments.class, v.getAppointmentId());
                t_id= var.getVisitId();
                cont.addItem(t_id);
                Resources res = (Resources)session.load(Resources.class, v.getReferredBy());
                cont.getContainerProperty(t_id, "Patient").setValue(var.getFirstName() + " " + var.getLastName());
                cont.getContainerProperty(t_id, "Date Of Service").setValue(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(v.getVisitDt()));
                cont.getContainerProperty(t_id, "Provider").setValue(res.getResourceFirstName()+" "+res.getResourceLastName());


            }
```

When it executes the line "cont.getContainerProperty(t_id,property).setValue()
It occasionally throws NullPointerException. Not getting the reason behind it.

What can be the reason behind this , any help!

Thanks!

Comment: post the stacktrace please

Answer (score 0):

Without more details I would say either :

- `v.getVisitDt()` is null for some `v``
- `session.load(Resources.class, v.getReferredBy());` returns null for some `v` and so `res` is null.

This will probably fix the problem:

```
   cont.getContainerProperty(t_id, "Patient").setValue(var.getFirstName() + " " + var.getLastName());
 if(v.getVisitDt()!=null){
   cont.getContainerProperty(t_id, "Date Of Service").setValue(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(v.getVisitDt()));
 } else {
   cont.getContainerProperty(t_id, "Date Of Service").setValue("?");
 }
 if(res!=null){
    cont.getContainerProperty(t_id, "Provider").setValue(res.getResourceFirstName()+" "+res.getResourceLastName());
 else{
    cont.getContainerProperty(t_id, "Provider").setValue("?");
 }
```